# Why is my reddit comment bot commenting in all caps?

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

This bot reads a text file to post a random response when the keyboard is entered. However, It's sending in all caps when the txt file is written in proper grammar.

Sorry if I'm completely ignorant. I'm in early stages of learning and this is kind of my building block. This code isnt mine but I'm modifying it for my use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import praw
import random
import config

class Bot:

    def __init__(
            self,
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            username,
            password,
            user_agent,
            path_to_quotes,
            subreddit_name,
            trigger
        ):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.user_agent = user_agent
        self.path_to_quotes = path_to_quotes
        self.subreddit_name = subreddit_name
        self.trigger = trigger.lower()

        with open(self.path_to_quotes) as f:
            self.quotes = [q.upper() for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]

        self.number_quotes = len(self.quotes)

        self.reddit = praw.Reddit(
            client_id=self.client_id,
            client_secret=self.client_secret,
            user_agent=self.user_agent,
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password
        )

        self.subreddit = self.reddit.subreddit(self.subreddit_name)

        self.reset_buffer()

    def reset_buffer(self):
        self.used_quotes = []
        self.unused_quotes = list(range(self.number_quotes))

    def get_quotes(self):
        return self.quotes 

    def contains_trigger(self, comment):
        return self.trigger in str(comment.body).lower()

    def get_random_quote(self, comment):
        if not self.unused_quotes:
            self.reset_buffer()
 
        random_int = random.choice(self.unused_quotes)
        random_quote = self.quotes[random_int]

        author = '/u/' + str(comment.author)
        random_quote = random_quote.replace('!USERNAME', author)

        self.unused_quotes.remove(random_int)
        self.used_quotes.append(random_int)

        return random_quote

    def welcome_message(self):
        print('Posting as /u/' + self.username, 'on /r/' + self.subreddit_name)
        print('Trigger word is', self.trigger)
        print('Use <Ctrl> + c to exit')

    def start_stream(self):
        self.welcome_message()
        for comment in self.subreddit.stream.comments():
            trigger_status = self.contains_trigger(comment)
            same_author = str(comment.author).lower == config.username.lower()

            if trigger_status and not same_author:
                random_quote = self.get_random_quote(comment)
                comment.reply(random_quote)

def main():
    bot = Bot(
        client_id = config.client_id,
        client_secret = config.client_secret, 
        username = config.username, 
        password = config.password, 
        user_agent = config.user_agent, 
        path_to_quotes = config.path_to_quotes,
        subreddit_name = config.subreddit_name,
        trigger = config.trigger
    )

    bot.start_stream()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `self.quotes = [q.upper() for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]` is converting all the quotes you read from the file into uppercase, before doing anything with them. Replace `q.upper()` with `q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part here is your problem:

```
with open(self.path_to_quotes) as f:
        self.quotes = [q.upper() for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]
```

`q.upper()` takes whatever is in `q`, and makes it uppercase. You want this instead:

```
with open(self.path_to_quotes) as f:
        self.quotes = [q for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]
```

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question. If I were to put a sleep timer in there to stop it from posting too much, where would it go? I've been trying to figure out where the line is that actually sends the respond commend.

Comment: @rpm, hmm, that one's above my paygrade. Please post as a separate question and the community can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`self.quotes = [q.upper() for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]`

As you can see here, `q`, which is a line from your text file, gets converted to uppercase inside the list comprehension. `upper` is a method of string that converts all lowercase characters in a string to uppercase.

Remove the call to upper and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question. If I were to put a sleep timer in there to stop it from posting too much, where would it go? I've been trying to figure out where the line is that actually sends the respond commend.

Answer (score 1):

you are converting the quotes to upper case when you read the file in line 30

```
self.quotes = [q.upper() for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]
```

you can just delete `.upper()`

```
self.quotes = [q for q in f.read().split('\n') if q]
```

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question. If I were to put a sleep timer in there to stop it from posting too much, where would it go? I've been trying to figure out where the line is that actually sends the respond commend.